# Add column headers on regression output tables with etable / fixest

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to add column headers to my regression output table generated with the `fixest` package and `etable`.

I tried to add column headers using both a vector or a list. Here, an example from the documentation of `etable` (https://rdrr.io/cran/fixest/man/etable.html):

```
# first, 3 estimations
est_header = feols(c(Ozone, Solar.R, Wind) ~  poly(Temp, 2), airquality)

# header => vector: adds a line w/t title
etable(est_header, headers = c("A", "A", "B"))

# header => list: identical way to do the previous header
# The form is: list(item1 = #item1, item2 = #item2,  etc)
etable(est_header, headers = list("A" = 2, "B" = 1))
```

When using a vector, I get an error message:

```
Error in etable(est_header, headers = c("A", "A", "B")) : 
  The second element of '...' (named 'headers') is not valid: it should be a fixest object or a list, it is neither.
```

When using a list, the headers are not added either.